# Where to set server values in Jenkins UI

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, automated-tests

We currently hardcoded our server parameters in pom.xml with the projectProperties tag, but is there any way to set server values in Jenkins UI for each particular jenkins build?

Comment: Can you elaborate little more clearly?

Comment: Well, basically we want to run a soapUI test, currently we hardcoded server parameters in pom.xml file, but is there a way to set them in Jenkins dashboard?

Comment: You can use something like this, put a variable inside your pom file, like this  <properties>
         <server>${env.SERVER_ADDRESS}</server> </properties>, after that inside your jenkins job, create a parameter with same name, SERVER_ADDRESS, when you run your pom file in that job, this parameter will be injected into your pom file.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out.

Comment: Just one more question, can this method also applies to Apache Jmeter tests with Jenkins?

Comment: Not sure, never test it before.